# MySQL: SELECT field from table1 not present in table2

Tags: mysql, sql

Simplified my database looks like this:

```
CREATE
TABLE vinyls (
    id_vinyl INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                  
    PRIMARY KEY (id_vinyl),
    UNIQUE KEY id_vinyl (id_vinyl));

CREATE
TABLE orders (
    id_order INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,                               
    PRIMARY KEY (id_order),
    UNIQUE KEY id_order (id_order));  

CREATE
TABLE orders_vinyls (
    id_order INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    id_vinyl INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_order, id_vinyl),
    UNIQUE KEY id_vinyl (id_vinyl),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_order) REFERENCES orders (id_order) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_vinyl) REFERENCES vinyls (id_vinyl) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

It's designed to have one order containing several vinyls - table orders_vinyls.
I need to get vinyls which are available for a customer. 
Those are the ones with id_vinyl not in table orders_vinyls. 
And there might be a situation 
when orders_vinyls is empty which causes some difficulties for me.

I would appreciate your help guys.

UPDATE:
For instance
table vinyls: (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);

table orders: (1), (2), (3)

table orders_vinyls: (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)

So I need to get vinyls with id_vinyl 5 or 6 because they are not in table orders_vinyls.

Comment: Can you please also post some sample data with expected result set. That would help us to understand your problem better.

Comment: Ehm, where do you keep track of the user for the order? You can't make MySQL guess as to who made the order if you don't track it. Please edit your schema to include a user_id somewhere

Comment: If db is not simplified it includes users table and id_user as foreign key in table orders.

Comment: post your query which you have used .

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to select those vinyls not present in any order made, then one option is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM vinyls AS v
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM orders_vinuls AS ov 
                  WHERE ov.id_vinyl = v.id_vinyl)
```

This will also work in case table `orders_vinuls` is empty.

Comment: Got the same answer and i was the first one to use NOT EXISTS

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Well, if you look at the timestamp my answer is one minute earlier than yours.

Comment: Could not see it but could be writing the answer at the same time. No worries it's for the best

Comment: Also: do you think table orders_vinyls should have a composite primary key of id_order and id_vinyl or just id_vinyl will do?

Comment: @EgorTyurin This depends on the business logic that you want to implement. If `id_vinyl` is unique *irrespective* of its relation to  `id_order` then placing the PK on `id_vinyl` aloone is fine.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Yes, it's unique and auto incremented

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can just use the set difference operation `except`

```
select id_vinyl from vinyls
except
select id_vinyl from orders_vinyls
```

If your actual vinyls table is more complex, you can use the result of the query above joined with the original table, or you can use a different query

```
select  *
from    vinyls
where   id_vinyl not in (
            select id_vinyl from orders_vinyls
        )
```

Comment: NOT IN is good but not the fastest if you have a huge amount of data

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOT EXISTS

```
Select * from table1 a
Where not exists (select 1 from table2  b where b.vynil_id = a.vynil_id)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! For reference: I haven't tried queries from other answers yet.